# How can I create a standalone JavaScript bundle from my Gatsby website?

Tags: javascript, webpack, gatsby

I have a Gatsby website which is slowly replacing another one done in an ancient tech, page by page. I need to add some JavaScript to the old website. This code already exists in the new Gatsby website, so my idea is to somehow generate an extra JavaScript bundle from the Gatsby build process and include it where it's needed.

I assume something like this would be possible but I can't find any trace on the Internet of someone doing the same thing. My current plan is somehow modify [Webpack configuration](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/custom-configuration/add-custom-webpack-config/) to [add a new JavaScript entry point](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/#entry) in the hopes this will create an extra JavaScript bundle, whose name needs to be stable (no hashes nor versioning in any sense) and its content shouldn't be splitted across different chunks.

Another complication is how complex is the [Gatsby webpack config](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/gatsby%402.31.1/packages/gatsby/src/utils/webpack.config.js). We're currently using Gatsby version 2.31.1.

My first attempt was to simply add a new entry, pointing to a JavaScript file. There are so many stages, so I tried them all, one at a time, without success. No extra file is generated when running either `gatsby develop` nor `gatsby build`.

```
--- a/src/gatsby/gatsby-node.ts
+++ b/src/gatsby/gatsby-node.ts
@@ -55,24 +55,32 @@ export const onCreateWebpackConfig: GatsbyNode['onCreateWebpackConfig'] = ({
       }),
     })
   }
+
+  if (stage === 'build-javascript') {
+    actions.setWebpackConfig({
+      entry: {
+        customEntry: path.resolve('./src/custom-entry.js'),
+      },
+    })
+  }
 }
```

Any tips on how to accomplish this?

Comment: I assume that the snippet is cleaned from `+` and `-`, isn't it?

Comment: @FerranBuireu, yes. This is simply a git diff of my changes.